# Why mining bitcoins is difficult?

Tags: block-cipher, complexity, cryptocurrency

As I understand to obtain a Golden Block is to finding a nonce that matches a hash lower than a given target, as shown in [this research-gate article](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/The-Block-Hashing-Algorithm-of-bitcoin-revisited-and-seen-as-a-Constrained-Input-Small_fig2_258144528).

And here is a "py" kernel: [Bitcoin mining python (Github)](https://github.com/subhan-nadeem/bitcoin-mining-python)

As the nonce is only a 4 (8-bit)byte it is only to compare 65,536 hashes, that it seems ridiculous for any GPU.

So... Why is it difficult?

Comment: 4 bytes is $2^{32}$, not $2^{16}$; but there is no restriction on the nonce length in this code. It is "difficult" (slow; but embarrassingly parallizable) to brute force the hash to be less than the target.

Comment: What is the probability that a random input will have 4-byte zero 256-bit output of SHA-256?

Comment: @kelalaka I'd re-phrase your question for the OP as "What is the probability the hash of a random input starts with 4 zero bytes?" to disambiguate from $4/32$ zero bytes in any position.

Comment: Right ... I thought the nonce was 4 hexadecimal digits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 4294967296 nonces, because it is 32-bit.

Most of the time, *none* of the nonces will produce a "Golden Block". 
If none of the nonces work, the miner must make a new block (with a different Merkle root (256 bits) which means the block has different transactions in it) and try to mine that block instead.

Currently, about 99.999999994% of blocks don't have any valid nonce. That means the miner must try over 15 billion blocks before it finds one that has a nonce.

This is not a problem, because one of the transactions in a block is the one which gives the bitcoins to the miner. The miner can't change other peoples' transactions, but it can add extra unused bytes to its *own* transaction, which means the block has different transactions in it, and a different Merkle root.

Comment: Most of the time = ?

Comment: @kelalaka Currently, about 99.999999994% of blocks will not have any valid nonce.

Comment: That's correct! I thought the nonce was 4 hexadecimals. But even being 4,295 million it is still easy to obtain it in less than one second with a good GPU. So it is a question of milliseconds to be the winner?

Comment: "This is done by slightly changing the transaction that gives you the new bitcoins" .. can you explain this better?

Comment: Ok ... Imagine I can know when a block has not a valid nonce. I only have to wait to the one and then I only will spend 20 milliseconds of my GPU(s)

Comment: @IzarUrdin but you can't.

Comment: @IzarUrdin Imagine I can know which nonce is valid. I only have to find the valid nonce and then I will only spend 20 milliseconds of my GPU(s).

Comment: So the question is to know which block has a valid nonce? These 15.000 millions of blocks ... at what rate are transmitted? I have to discard 14.999 millions of blocks in how many time?

Comment: @IzarUrdin The blocks without valid nonces are not mined blocks. Those are blocks you tried to mine and failed. You can know because when you tried to mine them it didn't work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105399/discussion-between-izar-urdin-and-user253751).